# MVC/JQM iPhone/Chrome - page posting back to different controller

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I have an MVC4 application and I am seeing very odd behaviour on iPhone/Chrome only

Here is the happy path

- go to /account/register
- the register method of the account controller handles the request
- fill out the form and click join
- the register(signupModel) method of the account controller handles the event

here is what happens on iPhone/Chrome only

- go to /account/register
- the register method of the account controller handles the request
- fill out the form and click join
- the login(signupModel) method of the account controller handles the event

So I am baffled as to why the incorrect action is being called only on iPhone/iOS

- This has been tested on numerous mobile and desktop devices (android, iphone/safari) without a problem
- The site is MVC4/.Net4.0 and JQuery Mobile
- the IIS logs are showing a POST to /account/login so I do not think its a route problem.  It seems like the client really is posting to the wrong URL

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have come up with a partial fix.  If I explicitly add an action to the form tag of 

    action="/account/register"

then it works.  Still I would love to know the source of the issue

Comment: Okay, I am little closer to understanding what is going on here.

The way you navigate the site is as follows

- Click on Login and you go go to \account\login
- click on register JQM naviagtes you to \account\register 

the navigation works using ajax, so now I am not surprised that the action of the form i still \acccount\login

Question is - how do other browsers handle it coorectly?